# Better localStorage API

Tags: javascript, api, browser-storage

I wasn't quite happy with the way [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) handles non-string values, for example `localStorage.setItem("foo",{test:5});localStorage.getItem("foo");` returns string literal `'[object Object]'`, so i thought it would be a good idea to wrap it in json, came up with

```
betterLocalStorage = {
    get: function(key) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    },
    set: function(key, value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
};
```

and `betterLocalStorage.set("foo",{test:5});betterLocalStorage.get("foo");` returns object `{test: 5}`

Answer (score 2):

### Style

- Don't use undeclared variables, eg `betterLocalStorage` should be `const betterLocalStorage =`
- Use function property shorthand to define functions. Eg `get: function(key) {` can be `get(key) {`
- Avoid using `get` and `set` as property names as these are tokens used to define setters and getters.
- LocalStorage is an `Object`  you can use bracket notation to set and get properties though there is nothing wrong using `getItem` and `setItem`. However do not mix access methods. Also not tha `getItem` will return `null` rather than `undefined` if a property does not exist.

### Design

- Local storage is a limited resource and is shared with all code on your domain (including extensions, user injected, and 3rd party code). There  is no guarantee that data stored will be retrievable.
- Local storage can be blocked and or modified by extensions/user code. `JSON.parse` will throw if the string is not a correctly formed JSON string. You do not guard against such events.
- `JSON.stringify` will throw if the object being processed contains a cyclic reference. eg The following will throw an error. `const a = {b: {}}; a.b = a; betterLocalStorage.set("foo", a)`. Many object contain cyclic references so care must be taken.
- Your function pair `get`/`set` will convert `undefined` to `null`. Eg `const a; console.log(betterLocalStorage.get(betterLocalStorage.set(a))); /* >> null should be undefined */`

  This is counterintuitive if you are not aware, and becomes very problematic if you rely on default parameters in related code.
- Your code converts an `undefined` value to `null` (via get set pair). You should guard against this behaviour.
- If you use bracket notation (as in rewrite example) parsing a `undefined` property will throw an error. I do not use `getItem` and `setItem` due to its DOM centric behaviour. Which you use is up to you.

### Rewrite

The rewrite addresses the style and design issues outlined above.

```
const storage = {
  getItem(key) {
    try {
      return localStorage[key] === undefined ? undefined : JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
    } catch (e) {
      // TODO handle, report or pass on error
    }
    return; 
  },
  setItem(key, value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      try {
        localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
      } catch (e) {
        // TODO handle, report or pass on error
      }
    }
  }
};
```